# IF statement ignoring arguments

Tags: php, if-statement, arguments

I am trying to redirect the page dependent on whether a counter is the same as the size of an array. However the `IF` statement is ignoring its arguments and operating anyway. my code is;

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
include 'DayOffDateTest.php';
$usernameid = $_POST['usernameid'] ;
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$countme = 0;
$size = sizeof($dayOfTheWeek) - 1;
$size2 = sizeof($dayOfTheWeek);


for ($count = 0; $count <= $size; $count++) {   

$query = "SELECT title FROM daysoff WHERE date = '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]' AND reason <> ''";               
$result = mysql_query($query);       
$unavailable_users = array();                                                  
while($request = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                           
$unavailable_users[] = $request["title"];
}   
if(count($unavailable_users) < 3){
$countme = $countme + 1;
$query = "INSERT INTO daysoff (`title`, `date`,`reason`) VALUES ('$usernameid', '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]', '$reason')"; 
$toomany = array();
$dayoff = mysql_query($query);}

    else {
        $toomany[] = "There are to many users booked off for ". $dateMonthYearArr[$count] .", please speak to your manager.</br><hr width=100%>";
    }
}   $_SESSION['many'] = $toomany;

if($countme = $size2){

    header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ;
}
else{
    header('Location: ../toomany.php') ;
}
?>
```

It is the last `IF` statement, whose arguments are `$counter` and `$size2`, that is not working. I have echoed out the values and everything is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
if($countme = $size2){
```

should be

```
if($countme == $size2){
```

You are doing an assignment instead of comparison !

---

Sidenote : This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Thanks, don't know how i missed that